# Wordpress Subscriptions in laravel (corcel)

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel, jetpack

I have 2 projects, one in Wordpress, and the other one in Laravel 4.2.

Recently i had to merge both projects into one Laravel 4.2 App using jgrossi/corcel. This was my only option.

Everything works fantastic! I can even post directly into Wordpress without logging into Wordpress to get posts, comments, etc.

But there is something I can't figure out. Wordpress is using Jetpack for subscribers. The laravel app needs a field to add more subscribers. I have very little experience in Wordpress.

Is it possible to add subscribers from outside Wordpress directly into the database? If not, is there a way to use a Jetpack plugin outside of Wordpress?

Comment: If you can figure out where your users are created in Wordpress you could post directly to the link using a plain form. All you would need to do is get the url add that to your form url and post. You could also possibly do a post to laravel use that information to add the user to your laravel app then redirect in some way as a post (this isn't a normal HTTP action, but it may be possible if you read [this](http://laravel.io/forum/04-23-2014-redirectintended-with-routepost).

Comment: Are you able to solve this issue with adding data in `wp_users` and `wp_usersmeta` table..??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can add new users in database with subscribers role.

Wordpress stores the users data in `wp_users` table and its meta info in `wp_usermeta`. So follow the following steps

1. Add a new entry in `wp_users` table. As a sample here is entry from my `wp_users` table. You can submit values for these attributes using your normal laravel form with post request. [image]
2. Add its related data in `wp_usermeta` table. Here you need to set two key value attributes against `user_id` of newly inserted record.

   1. `meta_key = wp_capabilites` and `meta_value = a:1:{s:10:"subscriber";b:1;}`. As you can note the `meta_value` for `wp_capabilities` is in serialzed form.
   2. `meta_key = show_admin_bar_front` and `meta_value = true`.

So you added a new user with subscriber role.

Comment: But, i don't want to add new users, we are using jetpack for subscribers